# Why there are no bootstrap support for handling grid system breakpoint events ?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why there are no bootstrap support for handling grid system breakpoints events or menu collapsing (aka 981px)? May be there are official recommendations to use jquery $(window).resize or may be I just miss something?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you ever read bootstrap JavaScrip API documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ ? There are many events of various components but there are no events to support Grid System. I'm interesting why.

Answer (score 1):

For menu collapsing events, see Bootstrap documentation at [Dropdown Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events)

To answer the "grid system breakpoints events", there is a way to do this if you are asking for events to handle when different mediaquerys are active.  It is to use the Window.matchMedia() function.  There is an excellent tutorial at [Window.meadiawatch tutorial](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/).  Below is part of the tutorial that shows how to do this.

// Establishing media check
    width600Check = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)"),
    height500Check = window.matchMedia("(min-height: 500px)"),
    portraitOrientationCheck = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

```
// Add listeners for detecting changes
width600Check.addListener(setWidthValue);
height500Check.addListener(setHeightValue);
portraitOrientationCheck.addListener(setOrientationValue);

function setWidthValue (mediaQueryList) {
    width600.innerHTML = mediaQueryList.media;
}

function setHeightValue (mediaQueryList) {
    height500.innerHTML = mediaQueryList.matches;
}

function setOrientationValue (mediaQueryList) {
    portraitOrientation.innerHTML = mediaQueryList.matches;
}
```

Click [Browser Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) to see browser support.

Comment: Thank you I will read this article. I'm not common with mediaquerys concept, feel that I need to learn it...  But dropdown events (hide and show) have nothing common with menu collapsing when on window resize bootsrap "colapse" (remove) menus from navbar if window become smaller than 981 pixel.